# PHP: How to get the document root from inside a user directory?

Tags: php, apache, directory, document-root

I develop and deploy various PHP applications to different environments. Especially on development environments, they can be anywhere, from document_root to /Users/me/Sites/ or even /Users/me/Sites/someapp/

Inside these applications I need to know where the 'application root' is, once as the real path and once as URL. Path is no problem. Let's say I have a bootstrap.php in the app root directory which does:

```
define("BASE_DIR", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

However, I have problems to reliably get the base URL. On most environments simply subtracting document root from BASE_DIR works:

```
define("BASE_URL", str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',BASE_DIR) . "/");
```

Now, my problem is: This does not work on environments where my app lies inside my user directory because PHP still sees the main document root. Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find an application's base url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176712/how-can-i-find-an-applications-base-url)

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried the solution there and the result it gives depends on the location of the file including the given code.

Comment: Or rather: The solution requires the bootstrap.php to always be in the root directory (altough I said otherwise for simplicity's sake, I had it in an "includes/" directory). But I guess the simplest solution is to move it to the top and use the here-linked solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything involving realpath() and DOCUMENT_ROOT is going to fail hard when the server's got aliases configured. Consider a scenario where Apache's got a configuration like this:

```
DocumentRoot /home/httpd/html
Alias /testalias /home/otherdir
```

And you access a script at `example.com/testalias/script.php`.

The script will return:

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) -> /home/otherdir
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] -> /home/httpd/html
BASE_DIR -> /home/otherdir
BASE_URL -> /home/otherdir/
```

and yet the rest of the site actually exists in `/home/httpd/html`

You might have better luck reconstructing the URL based on `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, which is the path/script name portion of the URL:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] -> /testalias/script.php
```

Comment: Which is what the solution does which was linked by alexn as a possible duplicate. And I think he is right, the question is the same, but I still think the solution there only works in a bootstrap file in the application root.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176712/how-can-i-find-an-applications-base-url/185725#185725

Comment: I am using this when I am using Alias directory str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])

Comment: The problem with SCRIPT_NAME is that it is not static because it is based on the name of current executing script. 

Before Apache 2.3.x becomes popularly adopted to that we can use CONTEXT_PREFIX variable. I'm afraid there's no solution.