# How to make $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] reference to alias directory path and NOT wamp default path?

Tags: apache, wamp, alias, wampserver, document-root

I currently have my WAMP installation at:

```
C:/wamp/www/
```

**My issue:**

When calling `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` from `localhost/projectname1/test.php` - this outputs:

```
C:/wamp/www/
```

This is no good since path in my scripts will be wrong then. I this case I want Document root to output (which is my alias path for this dummy project):

```
C:\Users\SGS\Google Drive\_Work\projectname1\html/
```

All my working files are on google drive, so for each project I create an Apache alias, that points to the direct path of the project located on google drive folder.

Example of an alias created - `projectname1.conf`:

```
Alias /projectname1/ "C:\Users\SGS\Google Drive\_Work\projectname1\html/"

<Directory "C:\Users\SGS\Google Drive\_Work\projectname1\html/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This allow me to call the project with `localhost/projectname1/`

How do I get my document?

Comment: http://sa-os.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-change-document-root-on-wamp.html ?

Comment: Hi Sarah, thanks for the suggestion. I did actually already try this - however the issue with this is that it will make the document root "static" and regardless of projectfolder all reference to: C:/Users/SGS/Google Drev/_Work/ .
As in my one project example - document root would need to reference to C:\Users\SGS\Google Drive\_Work\projectname1\html/

Comment: All DOCUMENT_ROOT contains is the info from your server's configuration file. PHP doesn't follow WAMP's aliases like this. You might try deconstructing one of the other $_SERVER variables like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634869/php-how-to-get-the-document-root-from-inside-a-user-directory

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better creating a Virtual host for each of your projects.

[HowTo setup Virtual Hosts](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,114458,114527#msg-114527)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with SCRIPT_NAME is that it is not static because it is based on the name of current executing script. Before Apache 2.3.x becomes popularly adopted so that we can use CONTEXT_PREFIX variable, I'm afraid there's no solution.